# I am trying to show product name releated to Menu category using laravel 7

Tags: laravel

I am using Yajra DataTable and  I am trying to show the product name related to the Menu category but unfortunately not showing the project name how can I resolve that please help me thanks.

[image]

**return $productCategory**

[image]

**WebMenu**

```
  public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'products_categories', 
         'product_category_id', 'product_id');
    }
```

**Product Model**

```
 public function webMenu()
    {

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\WebMenu', 'products_categories', 'product_id', 'product_category_id');
    }
```

**Controller**

```
 public function datatable()
    {
        // gets the selects colums only
        $productCategory = WebMenu::with('product')->whereHas('product', function 
         ($query) {
            $query->where('parent_id','!=', 0);
        })->get();
        return DataTables::of($productCategory)->make();
    }
```

**Jquery datatable**

```
  var table = $('#datatable').DataTable({
      processing: true,
      serverSide: true,
      ajax: '{{ route("project.datatable") }}',
      "columns": [
        { "data": "id", "defaultContent": "" },
        { "data": "name", "defaultContent": "" },
        { "data": "product_name", "defaultContent": "" },

        @if ($count > 0)
        { "data": "id", "defaultContent": "" },
        @endif
      ],
      "columnDefs": [{
        "targets": 'no-sort',
        "orderable": false,
      },
```

Answer (score -1):

change function controller like this

```
 public function datatable()
    {
        // gets the selects colums only
        $productCategory = WebMenu::with(['product' => function 
         ($query) {
            $query->where('parent_id','!=', 0);
        }])->get();
        return DataTables::of($productCategory)->make();
    }
```